# If I can develop app for apple smartwatch to get raw PPG data and implement my own algorithm for hear rate detection

Tags: ios, iphone, wear-os, sony-smartwatch, wearables

Can I  develop my own app for apple smartwatch through which I can get raw data from the PPG sensor of smartwatch and implement my own heart rate detection algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no direct access to the heart rate sensor hardware.  You can only access the data provided by HealthKit.